# Is it reasonable/realistic for a 6 year old to not be very different in 6 years?

Tags: biology

[image: Vivio's family]

above in a image of Vivio Takamachi with her Godmother Fate on the left and Adoptive Mother Nanoha to the right. Given how Einhald is not in the image it would be set during Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS when Vivio was 6.

I am writing a fan fiction which expands on the series occurring 6 year after this (technically 5 but Strikers started in one year finished in the next) where Vivio is now 12 years old. in it Fate and Nanoha are now dating and both are active as Vivio's mothers (though before then Vivio had always called them Feito-mama and Nanoha-mama)

When i imagine the 3 of them as a family while i write i still imagine Vivio being coddled by her mothers and carried like a child, in some sports Vivio refers to her mothers passionate/intimate kissing as them "making love", in another she is about to cry because her mothers are about to fly off to fight and she's scared they may not come back (because just previously another character shield her girlfriend from an attack and is in a coma as a result)

however i don't remember how i was like when i was 6 and 12 but i can't see myself being any different, even size wise but this could just be my memory from back there being shoddy.

so i am wondering, with the exception to intelligence (because of school), is it reasonable/realistic to assume that a 6 year old, being raised in a loving family, won't be all that different in 6 years?

If not, is there something i can use to describe that it's totally normal for her not to have changed much (if at all) in 6 years (using a 12 month calendar) since all children her age are like that (she's not smaller/immature/greatly younger compared to her school friends), rather than opting to say "because i love little Vivio being doted and cuddled by her mothers"? (kinda the truth, it's so f***** cute!)

NOTE: if you've seen the series then ignore Vivio's origins and assume she's a normal girl

Comment: You could take your own pictures at age 6 and at age 12 to see the difference, there is usually quite a difference. Also you can look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtyqS68ViWk) of a girl from age 0 to 12 to see how ageing occurs. Also don't neglect the difference in height. [This statistics](http://www8.cao.go.jp/youth/english/whitepaper/2006/images/table1.gif) says that there's almost 40 cm of height difference between an average 6-year old and an average 12-year old.

Comment: Is this about a 6 years old *human*, or a 6 years old *something else*? If the latter, you may want to look up the Star Trek species Ocampa: they generally don't even live to become 12 years.

Comment: This seems off topic.  It's not about world creation, just a single character in an existing setting.

Comment: I agree this is definitely off topic.

Comment: @smithkm I wasn't actually just referring to her but using her as a basis to then be applied generally to 12 year olds, hence why i said *"since all children her age are like that (she's not smaller/immature/greatly younger compared to her school friends)"*. however i wasn't sure if this was entirely off topic since i was trying to define characteristics of a subset of people in the world (in this case 12 year olds) which in my opinion was defining a part of the culture of a world but then again i may be wrong in that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it reasonable/realistic to assume that a 6 year old, being raised in a loving family, won't be all that different in 6 years?

Well the answer to the first part of your question is no, children change a lot in 6 years. A 6 year old will be interested in toys, the first years of school and will still be learning basic social skills.

A 12 year old will be starting / going through puberty (although some people start as late as 14), will have very different interests than a 6 year old, will possibly be starting to become more interested in the world around them (generally through social media) and whilst still playing games,  they would be different from those of a 6 year old.

> If not, is there something i can use to describe that it's totally normal for her not to have changed much (if at all) in 6 years (using a 12 month calendar) since all children her age are like that

For the second part of your question, this is fiction. If you want it so children don't change and can come up with a reason why all children don't change then go for it. It's your world and your creativity,  just make it believable if you want any of your readers to buy into it.

Answer (score 1):

Not having any idea about Vivio's origins, the only reason why a human-seeming being may be the same six years after age six is that for some reason she has reached - or has nearly reached - her full potential at age six.  If, for example, she was actually some sort of robot/cyborg, or a humanoid alien with a different life cycle, or she has some sort of genetic disorder meaning that she will neither grow nor mature any further, or just *magic*.

That said, if we're talking about anime, any of that is possible...